# How to get the postfix work?

Tags: linux, postfix

Briefly describle my testing env

- window7 (192.168.0.10) with vmware server 45G virtual harddisk with CentOS 6 (192.168.0.13), router Dmz 192.168.0.13
- everything(http, ftp, ssh, mysql, phpmyadmin) work ok except postfix and squirrelmail
- a no-ip domain name
- installation -> webmin -> virtualmin

Email testing case 1:

- click webmin->postfix mail server->userbox->userA->compose->
- send an email to userB, address is userB@localhost
  click webmin->postfix mail server->userbox->userB->
- no email inside (This user has no message in ~userB/Maildir/)
- initially, Maildir doesn't exist
- then i check /var/spool/mail/userB, i can see the recevied email

Email testing case 2:

- click webmin->postfix mail server->userbox->userA->compose->
- send an email to userB, address is userB@realdomain.no-ip.com
  click webmin->postfix mail server->userbox->userB->
- no email inside (This user has no message in ~userB/Maildir/)
- initially, Maildir doesn't exist
- then i check /var/spool/mail/userB, i can't see the recevied email

how to troubleshoot the email server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the log files. This is why they exist. Depending on which Linux you have you see them in `/var/log/mail`, `/var/log/mail.log` or similar. In all cases you should find something under `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't `/var/log/syslog` on CentOS. Another one to look is `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: thanks, most of the problems are fixed. There are else problems. The email server can't send out(e.g send an email to google), and the home/user/mailDir don't have emails, need to go to /var/spool/mail/user